# LUA psvita TOUCH boton

Tags: xcode, lua, touch, game-center, playstation

I'm learning Lua, but I don't understand how to create a button?
http://onelua.x10.mx/vita/docs/es/group__touch.html      my reference

```
    if touch.front.count(1).x(100).y(100).pressed then  screen.print(400,400,"ok",1,color.white,color.green)end
```

did not get a button in exact coordinates

the whole screen works with a single button with this code

if touch.back[1].held
if touch.fron[1].held

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this:

```
if touch.front.count(1).x(100).y(100).pressed then

    screen.print(400,400,"ok",1,color.white,color.green)
    
end
```

If that isn't the solution then you gave the wrong variable to touch or screen.

Comment: I think I'll try to draw the button and then place the co-ordinates draw.rect(100,100,200,100,color.red)end then if touch.front.count(1).x(100).y(100).pressed see what happens